# How do I find the most recent git commit that modified a file?

Tags: git, search

I want to find the most recent commit that modified a source file.

I can use `git blame` to see all the dates for commits by each line, but it’s difficult to see exactly which commit was the last one to touch the file.

How can I find the last commit that touched a given file in my git repository?

Answer (score 349, accepted):

[`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) supports looking at the history of specific files (and directories), so you can call it like this:

```
git log my/file.c
```

If you really only want to list the *one* most recent commit, for example to use it in a script, use the `-n 1` option:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H -- my/file.c
```

`--pretty=format:%h` tells `git log` to show only the commit hash. The `--` separater stops the file name from getting interpreted as a commit name, just in case it's ambiguous.

Comment: If you want to know the last time a file was modified no matter the branch, you can consider all branches by adding the `--all` option.

Comment: I'm having to add a `--` before the filepath, e.g. `git log -- my/file.c`.

Comment: note that this will work only in static environment, meaning if re-clone your repository, commit hashes will be changed.

Comment: @dzona you say "if re-clone your repository, commit hashes will be changed". That sounds wrong, commit hashes are the same in each new clone.

Answer (score 82):

If you just want to *find* the most recent commit, then you don't want `git-log`, you want `git-rev-list`, which lists the commit objects changing that file, in that commit path, starting with the most recent one (chronologically).  Simply put:

`git rev-list -1 <commit> <filename>`

For `git-rev-list` in your case, you just supply:

- The number of commits to include, or **-1** for only the most recent,
- The branch (or commit id) to start looking back from, **HEAD** if you are already on it, or **--all** if you want all known commits, and
- The relative path to your file.

This just returns the most recent commit ID in the current branch to alter that file, ex: `215095e2e338525be0baeeebdf66bfbb304e7270`

For a more complex example, you can use tag names, and even remote references, and include relative path names with wildcards, for ex:

`git rev-list origin/user/bob/testbranch -1 src/bfiles/*.txt`

...Which would tell you what the most recent change was to the wildcard match in that branch's history.  The options for rev-list are extreme, it is one of the most important plumbing commands, so you can include or exclude by just about any criteria you can imagine.

Of course, refer to the [git-rev-list(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html).

Comment: You really did not explain why using `git-log` is inferior.

Comment: I would not say inferior, just that it provides extraneous information by default.  git-rev-list just returns the commit ID, which is what you want if you are going to feed the response into a script or other automation process.  git-log returns information about the selected commits, first by using git-rev-list to gather the commit ids, then gathering information on each commit.  If you are just going to filter out the commit information and use the ids, then you can just use git-rev-list in the first place.  Since log is based on rev-list, it takes most of the same filter parameters.

Comment: `git-log` is porcelain, `git-rev-list` is plumbing.

Comment: please note that if you merged a commit from a different branch, this method will not give you the merge commit (as I had expected, because it is the commit that introduces this change to my branch) but the original commit that was merged. Just something to keep in mind. Haven't found a command to get the merge commit yet, but I'm sure there is one

Answer (score 31):

If you want to just get the hash of the latest commit to modify a specific set of files (and want to avoid `awk`) you can use:

```bash
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h -- <path>
```

This can be useful for getting the commit hash for subsequently using with `git describe`.

For example (in case it's useful for anyone)…

I create a current version id by considering the latest commit to change any source file (assuming you mark versions with tags like `mycode-1.2.1`):

```bash
COMMIT=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%h -- *.c *.h)
if VN=$(git describe --always --abbrev=5 --match "mycode-*" $COMMIT 2>/dev/null) &&
case "$VN" in
mycode-*)
    git update-index -q --refresh
    test -z "$(git diff-index --name-only HEAD *.c *.h)" ||
    VN="$VN-mod" ;;
*) VN="mycode-unknown-g$VN" ;;
esac
then
    continue
else
VN="mycode-unknown"
fi
```

This produces ids like:

- **`mycode-1.2.1`** - when the current state of the source files corresponds to a tagged version
- **`mycode-1.2.1-g3k7s2`** - when the current state of the source files corresponds to commit following a tagged version
- **`mycode-1.2.1-g3k7s2-mod`** - when the current state of the source files have been modified since the last commit following a tagged version
- **`mycode-unknown`** - when there has not yet been a version tag created

Comment: `$VN` looks like some kind of nightmare undead SVN

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but if you do a `git log <thefile>` to get the commits that altered that file. You can pick the topmost one. It should be the one you're looking for.

Comment: if you use `git log -n1 -- <thefile>` (or pipe the output to `head -1` if you want to waste resources) you don't have to manually pick the top line (see Jo Liss's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784575/how-do-i-find-the-most-recent-git-commit-that-modified-a-file/4784629#4784629))

Comment: Good point. I think you can also skip the `-n` and use `-1` directly.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the SHA id of the commit you want to look at using `git log FILENAME`, you should be able to do `git show SHA_ID_HERE` to see what you did for that particular commit. You don't even need to enter the entire ID; the first 6 characters should be enough.

Comment: that's a bit more than the OP asked for, but FYI you can combine this into a one-liner: `git show $(git log -1 --pretty="%H" -- FILENAME)`

Answer (score 3):

To get just the ref on one line, try:

```
git log -n1 --oneline <path> | awk '{print $1;}'
```