# git: list all file names and the hashes of their latest commit

Tags: git

I would like to get a list of all files in my branch, preferably in a tree view, together with the hash of the commit they have last been modified in (i.e. not the hash of the file itself but of the commit). Is there a neat git-command to do this, or do I really have to crawl through the log?

This question is related to [How do I find the most recent git commit that modified a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784575/how-do-i-find-the-most-recent-git-commit-that-modified-a-file/4784629#4784629) but I want to get a list of all files, for example:

```
6f88a51 abc.h
3f5d6fb abc.cpp
3f5d6fb bcd.h
1964be2 bcd.cpp
...
```

Comment: How about `git log <branch> --` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Command:

`$ git ls-files -z \
  | GIT_PAGER= xargs -0 -L1 -I'{}' git log -n 1 --format="%h {}" -- '{}' 
f5fe765 LICENSE
0bb88a1 README.md
1db10f7 example/echo.go
e4e5af6 example/echo_test.go
...`

Notes:

- `git ls-files` lists all files added to git recursively (unlike `find`, it excludes untracked files and `.git`)
- `xargs -L1` executes given command for every input argument (filename)
- `xargs -I{}` enables substitution of `{}` symbol with input argument (filename)
- using `git ls-files -z` and `xargs -0` changes delimiter from `\n` to `\0`, to avoid potential problems with white-spaces in filenames
- clearing `GIT_PAGER` prevents `git log` from piping it's output to `less`

Comment: arigato, very nice! blue112 solution also works fine, however I find yours nicer

Comment: Nice!  Here is a version in Powershell:

`git ls-files | foreach { git log -n 1 --format="$_ %h" -- $_ }`

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in $(find -type f | grep -v '.git'); 
    do echo -n "$i - "; 
    git log --pretty="format:%h" -1 $i | cat; 
    echo; 
done
```

That should do the trick, on bash

Comment: thanks, also gives me what I want, but I liked gavvs solution better as it's more elegant

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the ls-tree command

```
git ls-tree HEAD
```

This will show you the latest files with their hashes.

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. It shows the SHA-1 of the blobs and trees (which OP explicitly stated he does not want) instead of the SHA-1 of the latest commit which touched the files.

Comment: @Alderath is right, it shows file hashes, not commit hashes. Also, it doesn't print directories recursively.

Comment: Though this is not what's expected, git ls-tree -r HEAD could show all the blobs in the HEAD's tree.

Comment: this is exactly what I did not want, but thanks for thinking along ;)

Comment: Help op or not, this post is useful for my use case, so thanks!