# In Git, version information is not stored in header, is there way to know the file on customer instance before fixing the issue to ensure correct fix?

Tags: git

I am using GIT version control.

Here is what I want to accomplish

- Customer A identifies a defect in the product and logs an issue#1234
- Developer wants to know the file (sample.sql) on customer A instance before fixing it. The same file name may have high water mark content with other customer B, may be because of some other issue#5678.
- Its possible that customer A may not have applied the issue#5678
- Effectively, developer wants to know exact file definition of customer A (sample.sql) in order to provide an accurate fix.

My Questions

- Since version information is not stored in header, is there ay other way to address such issues?
- At a file level, there is no git commit information. Can any other way like tagging all the files and storing it customer instance as a filenaifest help me address this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the most recent git commit that modified a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784575/how-do-i-find-the-most-recent-git-commit-that-modified-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in git but it would be simple enough to do a simple diff if you have the customer send you the file in question. Alternatively you can ask the customer to perform a sha1 or md5 hash. Then you can compare the files from git with the same tool. Git also uses sha1 internally but it might not be easy to match the exact same match. I'm assuming git is not part of the customer deployment.

You can insert a comment into each file with the git hash during deployment. Of course this can be tampered with but that might not be an issue.