# How to checkout most recently updated version of a file across all branches in Git?

Tags: git

I've updated a file throughout my work on my Git repository on the `master` branch. I'm currently on another branch based on a much older commit to `master`, so the version of the file I'm seeing is out of date. I have not touched the file on my current branch.

I want to checkout the fully-updated version of that file. I know that the most recently updated version of that file (even across all branches) is the one I want, but I do not know which commit that is.

**Is there a way to checkout the most recently updated version of a given file across all branches and commits?** (I'm hoping for a one-liner.)

Answer (score 1):

If your file is `dir/foo`, then the way to get the most recent commit across all branches is as follows (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774290/1180930) or the [git-rev-list(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html)):

```
git rev-list -1 --branches=* dir/foo
```

The way to checkout a file based on a commit is (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/reset-or-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git)):

```
git checkout <commit> dir/foo
```

Therefore, a one-liner solution (in, e.g., BASH) is:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -1 --branches=* dir/foo` dir/foo
```