# Is there a way to find all the files changed in a git branch from a certain path?

Tags: git

I've been working on a project from a few months now and I'm moving to a new version and I need to check if the changes have been done by someone else or find what is different.  Is there a way to look back at my branch and only see the files that have changed in a certain folder over a number of commits?

Thanks

Kieran

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the most recent git commit that modified a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784575/how-do-i-find-the-most-recent-git-commit-that-modified-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `git log` on your local clone of the repo :

```
# this will list the commits that touched target files or directories :
git log --graph -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2
git log --graph -- path/to/directory

# add the -p option if you want to view the diff for each commit at the same time :
git log --graph -p -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

Comment: Thanks.  So it shows me the logs, is there a way for it to show me the individual files that have been changed, not the diff?

Comment: `--name-only` or `--name-status` instead of `-p`. These options works with all commands that show the content of a commit : `git log`, `git show`, `git diff` ...

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Get all files that have been modified in git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641361) for a way to get a list of all the files that differ between branches. We can `grep` that to narrow the scope to a particular path:

```
git diff --name-only origin/<branch> main | grep <path>
```

For example:

```
> git diff --name-only origin/feature-a main | grep static/scss
static/scss/_questionview.scss
static/scss/payments/payment-browse.scss
static/scss/payments/payment-summary.scss
```